ElasticSearch highlight with number of pragments
In ElasticSearch, when specify number_of_fragments to 0 to retrieve all content of field, i see that it highlights all the token matched with the search term and it's wrong when the search term can be tokenized into 2 or more tokens.
"must" => [
        %{
          "query_string" => %{
            "default_operator" => "AND",
            "fields" => ["message_parse"],
            "query" => "success after"
          }
        },
        %{"match_phrase" => %{"message_parse" => %{"query" => "success after"}}}
      ]

result:
   "highlight" => %{
      "message_parse" => ["<em>success</em>_<em>after</em> and <em>success</em> before and <em>after</em> abc <em>success</em> <em>after</em>"]
    },


Using highlight query with match phrase query solve my case
